# SQL queries in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an assignment to write a query to get the product name, quantity on hand, category, and unit price for all products in Baked goods and Dried fruits and nuts using the northwind 2007 database. My query look like this:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, QUANTITY_PER_UNIT, CATEGORY, LIST_PRICE
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE CATEGORY = [Dried Fruits & Nuts] OR [Baked Goods & Mixes];
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably:

```
SELECT 
    PRODUCT_NAME, QUANTITY_PER_UNIT, CATEGORY, LIST_PRICE
FROM 
    PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN 
    CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORYID = CATEGORIES.CATEGORYID
WHERE 
    CATEGORIES.DESCRIPTION = "Dried Fruits & Nuts" 
    OR 
    CATEGORIES.CATEGORY = "Baked Goods & Mixes";
```